# Is there a shorter way to replace all letters in an input? - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a thing that needs to replace all letters in the alphabet taken from a user's input but I think just doing it this way is way too long. Is there a better way to do this?

Im using python 3, b in the code is the input, and dot is the name of the list with stuff to replace

```
a1 = b.replace("a", dot[0])
  a2 = a1.replace("b", dot[1])
  a3 = a2.replace("c", dot[2])
  a4 = a3.replace("d", dot[3])
  a5 = a4.replace("e", dot[4])
  a6 = a5.replace("f", dot[5])
  a7 = a6.replace("g", dot[6])
  a8 = a7.replace("h", dot[7])
  a9 = a8.replace("i", dot[8])
#.... Continues
```

Comment: What is `dot` here? Can you share it?

Comment: dot is just a list filled with specific numbers that I want to replace the letters with

Comment: you can encode in hex the alphabet and cycle over it (using an index) with something like `for i in range(0,8) b.replace( a hex code + i, dot[0+i]`

Comment: I havent experimented with hex codes at all really, how would that work in a scenario for making the entire alphabet into whats in the list?

Comment: Is there a relationship between dot[0] and 'a' that can be expressed mathematically? What are you doing with uppercase letters? How many new variables do you want? Please show the declaration of *dot*

Comment: @AshHanson sorry maybe it's better in ASCII. A is 65, B 65+1, C 65+2 etc. Lower Case are +32 to Upper Case. [This](https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/466/410/png-transparent-ascii-character-binary-code-hexadecimal-string-korean-alphabet-miscellaneous-angle-text.png) is an ASCII table for reference

Comment: I found an easy method from one of the other people answering this, and sorry I cant show the declaration of dot

Comment: Thanks for the info, Ill probably use this sometime in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea is to convert the character into an integer, add 1 to it and then cast the resultant integer to char. You can achieve this using the builtin methods ord and chr.

```
prev=b

for i in range(26):
   cur=prev.replace(chr(ord('a')+i), dot[i])
   prev=cur
```

Answer (score 5):

With the replacement in a dictionary we can use `str.translate` as long as you only need to replace single characters.

```py
dotmap = {'e':'3', 'o':'0', ...}
txt = 'Hello world'

replacements = txt.maketrans(dotmap)
ntxt = txt.translate(replacements)
```

Which will return `H3ll0 w0rld`.

Comment: cool, didn't know that strings can `translate()`

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing `dot` contains the replacement characters for each alphabet. You could do something like

```
import string

s = 'example'
dot = '12345'

for c, cnew in zip(string.ascii_lowercase, dot):
    s = s.replace(c, cnew)

print(s)  # prints '5x1mpl5'
```

Explanation: `zip` pairs together the lowercase ASCII characters and the replacement characters. Then we get each pair in turn as `c` and `cnew`. `s` becomes the new string and the loop is repeated until either `dot` or the lowercase alphabet is exhausted.

Comment: I cant use a string due to my specific project, how would this work with a list instead?

Comment: It would work in the exactly identical way. Just replace `dot` with a list of characters.